# wampmysqld service is not starting

Tags: mysql, wamp

when i start wampmysqld service it gives following error:

```
Windows could not start the wampmysqld service on Local Computer.
Error 1067:The process terminated unexpectedly.
```

and MySQL log shows error as:

```
2014-02-07 12:42:36 5492 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2014-02-07 12:42:36 5492 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2014-02-07 12:42:36 5492 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2014-02-07 12:42:36 5492 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2014-02-07 12:42:36 5492 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2014-02-07 12:42:36 174c  InnoDB: Error: unable to create temporary file; errno: 2
2014-02-07 12:42:36 5492 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2014-02-07 12:42:36 5492 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2014-02-07 12:42:36 5492 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2014-02-07 12:42:36 5492 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Comment: _“InnoDB: Error: unable to create temporary file”_ – in what location did you install the database? Does your user account have write permissions there?

Comment: A few clues might help, like version of WAMPServer(32 or 64 bit) you installed, Verison of MySQL you are using, OS (32 or 64 bit). You know just a couple of clues.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a `TMP=` set in your environment.

When this is missing it can sometimes cause a problem.

Fix:

either to set that in your environment

OR

Set this in your my.ini

```
tmpdir=c:/wamp/tmp
```

Or any folder of your choise to hold MySQL's temp files.

Comment: Thanks a lot @RiggsFolly.I had been facing this issue for so many days.All the solutions mentioned elsewhere on the internet didn't work for me until i came across your solution.I tried your suggestion and now its working.